# TFS Security - Browsr Server

Tags: tfs-2015, tfs-security

I have set up TFS Security using Active Directory groups and in source control explorer through Visual Studio, users only see Team Projects that they have access to. However if they go to Team Explorer and click on the drop down menu they see almost all the team projects. If they go to web Tfs as well, the behaviour is exactly the same.

How do i restrict them to only see projects in dropdown that they have access to?
[image]

Project Collection Valid Users Group - Permissions
[image]

Project Collection Test Service Accounts - Permissions
[image]

Project Collection Service Accounts - Permissions
[image]

Project Collection Proxy Service Accounts - Permissions
[image]

Project Collection Build Service Accounts - Permissions
[image]

Project Collection Build Administrators - Permissions
[image]

--At Project Level--

All Project Valid Users group at Project Level are members of Project Collection Valid Users group
[image]

User Access From Collection Level:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

You need to **add the user/groups to the specific team project** but not in Collection level. Thus , the restricted user/groups can only see the specific team projects which they have permissions under the collection.

In **Team Explorer** you can select the projects which you want to connect/display.

**Update:**

1. Add the group under specific **team project** (Set permissions in
   Project level)
2. Add the same group under the specific **collection**
3. Under the collection security set "**View Collection Level
   Information**" to "**Deny**" for the group (Set permissions in Collection
   level)

Then the users in the group will can only access TFS with project permissions.

[image]

Comment: that is how i have set up security. adding users to individual team project and not at collection level.

Comment: @Baahubali Based on my test, please check the user/groups under Collection > Security, make sure they are not the member of  below groups : ''Project Collecion Administrators", "Project Collecion Build Services  Accounts", "Project Collecion Services Accounts", "Project Collecion Test Service Account".

Comment: checked and they are not members of those groups. they are only members of project collection valid users group.

Comment: @Baahubali Just try to clean the caches in you client machine also for your browser. then try it again.

Comment: i already tried that. this has been going on for last couple of years. it happens with all new and existing clients.

Comment: @Baahubali Have you checked membership of the users in the Group? Just check one of the user to see which group is it belonged? If the user is a member of multiple Team Projects, then it can see the projects accordingly. And make sure the user is not the member of the groups mentioned above. Just check the "User name or Scope" under "Member of", normally it should display the available project.

Comment: i have already done. The users are members of multiple team projects but they are not members of some of the projects that gets displayed in the dropdown. They don't see those projects in the source control explorer but only in the drop down menu.

Comment: @Baahubali Everything works at my side, please make sure there are no membership nested to the collection level groups.

Comment: I have provided multiple screenshots of the security groups at the collection level. may be they are incorrectly overridden?

Comment: @Baahubali I note that actually you are in collection level, normally the group you added should be the member of  Project valid users but not the Project collection valid users group, please try to delete the group, then create TFS group under specific project, then check it again. Please see the updated screenshot for reference.

Comment: All Project Valid Users group in the project level are member of Project Collection Valid Users group (Updated with screenshot).

Comment: @Baahubali Yeah, Project Collection Valid Users group is the ultimate group, all other groups are all the members of it. But I mean that under the specific project to check your group, make sure your group not displayed separately under the collection security. And you can just try to add a new user exactly following the steps mentioned above to check this issue. I checked this several times, it always works.

Comment: I have provided one more screenshot. Browsing to the collection level, i can go to the Users tab and from there let's say a user who i know don't have many permissions but can still some Team Projects in the drop down menu that he doesn't have access to. I have shown his permissions.

Comment: @Baahubali Please try to set View Collection Level Information to "Deny" for the user or group, then try it again.

Comment: if i take that permission away, then no one can access TFS at all.

Comment: @Baahubali According to my test, if you have added the Group to the specific project, then under the collection security set "View Collection Level Information" to "Deny" for the group or users, then the users in the group can only access TFS with project level information. So, please double check you have added the users/Group to the specific team projects.

Comment: @Baahubali I updated the answer, please try following the steps set the permission, then check if that works.